# Proving the existence of global solution for a family of Cauchy problems

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Consider the family of Cauchy problems
$$y'=\frac{1}{1+ty},~~t>0$$
with initial conditions
$$y(0)=1+\frac{1}{n}.$$
I want to show that for every $n$ there exists a solution $y_n$ defined on the whole set $\{t \in \mathbb{R}: t \geq 0 \} $.

I'm stucked because I don't see how I could even apply Picard-Lindelöf theorem, since $f(t,y) =\frac{1}{1+ty}$ diverges on the subset $\{(t, y): y=-\frac{1}{t}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2.$

What am I missing here? Any hint or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand the proof of Picard-Lindelöf? You are right that it doesn't apply directly, but the argument should be able to establish existence. The reason the divergence you pointed out doesn't matter is that $y$ will always be positive because if $y(s)=0$ then $y'(s)=1$, so before the solution can cross below the axis it will always increase away from it.

Comment: Thank you @user293794 I think I got what you're saying. However, assuming I can apply Picard-Lindelöf, how can I conclude that there exists a solution defined on the whole positive semi-axis? Indeed Picard-Lindelöf allows me to deduce only the local existence of a solution.

Comment: There are global versions of Picard-Lindelöf - you can find them on this site. The upshot is that if you solve on some interval $[0,T]$ then you use the same argument to solve the Cauchy problem starting at $T$ with initial condition given by $y(T)$. If you keep on doing this, assuming your intervals don't shrink (which they shouldn't), you will obtain global existence.

Comment: @user293794 ok, thank you for your help!